# Why does Yocto Cve Check needs artifactory and took so long to find cves?

Tags: yocto, patch, yocto-recipe, cve, yocto-layer

I am new to Yocto and would like to know how Yocto Cve check works.

1. Cve Check finds the patched/unpatched on version number & patch added to the recipe. Is this the only 2 methods Cve Check use?
2. Cve Check seems to fetch the package artifactory from jFrog. If 1 is true, why do we need to do this? We could just compare the version number & patch added from the metadata of the recipe.
3. If 1 is true, why Cve Check could take so many minutes (20 min+) for some packages to find its cve?